# Multiple maven projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I did the following in my latest eclipse with m2e plugini install:

- create a parent maven project
- right click on the maven project, create 2 maven modules under the parent project 
  Note: at this point I have 3 projects in my eclipse
- then share my project through svn (e.g http:xxx.xxx.myproject/trunk)
- define the scm section in my parent pom

then my team mate trying to check out the project by doing the following

- select import --> import maven project from scm --> give the url http:xxx.xxx.myproject/trunk

Now our problem is:

after he checks out the project, **instead of 3 there is ONLY one project** (the parent project), in his eclipse workspace.

unless I right click the folder which contains the sub-module then select import maven project.
**the sub-module won't AUTOMATICALLY checkout as a PROJECT.**

I certainly seen people check out the parent project, then all the sub-modules displays as projects in eclipse.

any hit please.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.
Create a project set and commit it to repository. Now your teammates can checkout the project set first and than import all the projects in single step from that project set.

My team used this approach in a past project. Although I didn't like it too much.

Here is link how to do part of it.
[Create Project Sets and Import projects from Project set](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-cvs-project-set.htm)

I hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is because after adding the modules, I have changed the module names in the parent pom. thats why! after correct the name, check out the project eveyrthing works.